# Prove that a continuous function on a metric space is uniformly continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

$A$ being a compact subset of a metric space $\Omega$ and $f: \Omega \to \Omega'$ continuous ($\Omega'$ is another metric space).
Show that $f$ on $A$ is uniformly continuous:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0\;\; \exists \delta > 0\;\; \forall x, y, \in A: d(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow d'(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$$

My idea:

Because $f$ is continuous, we know:

$$\forall \;\epsilon > 0 \;\;\exists \delta > 0\;\; \forall x, y \in A: $$
$$ d(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$$

(I hope that is correct).

But how can I transform $d(f(x), f(y))$ to $d'(f(x), f(y))$?

Comment: The part that $d(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$ is not implied by the continuity of $f$, in fact continuity gives you that for each $x_0\in \Omega$, $$d(x_0,y)<\delta \implies d'(f(x_0),f(y))<\epsilon$$ for some $\delta=\delta(x_0)>0$. 

Having $$d(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow d'(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$$ for any pair $x,y\in \Omega$ is exactly that $f$ is uniformly continuous.
---
A proof for the problem should use the compacity of $A\subseteq \Omega$.  A hint would be to consider an open covering of $A$ and use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the proof via the Lebesgue number lemma, you can also mimic the standard proof of the same fact for continuous functions $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, where $[a,b]$ is a non-degenerate compact interval. Suppose that your function is not uniformly continuous. Then:
$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall \delta > 0: \exists x,y \in A: d(x,y) < \delta \land d'(f(x),f(y)) \geq \epsilon$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be as above. Let $\delta_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, you can find two sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $A$ such that:
$$d(x_n,y_n) < \delta_n \land d'(f(x_n),f(y_n)) \geq \epsilon$$
Without loss of generality, we can assume that both sequences are convergent (why can we do this?), with limits $x$ and $y$ respectively. But now:
$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_n) + d(x_n,y_n) + d(y_n,y)$$
On the right hand side, each term goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. It follows that $d(x,y) = 0$ and since we are in a metric space, $x = y$. But now:
$$d'(f(x_n),f(y_n)) \leq d'(f(x_n),f(x)) + d'(f(x),f(y_n))$$
Since $y_n \to x$ and $f$ is continuous, it follows that the right-hand side goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. But this is impossible because it would imply that $0 \geq \epsilon$.

Comment: Why do we need the trick with the limits?

Comment: Which trick are you referring to?

Comment: Ok sorry never mind.
But how do we know that the two sequences from the beginning with the properties $<\delta_n$ and $\geq \epsilon$ exist?

Comment: Well, I have used the negation of the definition of uniform continuity. I know that for every $\delta > 0$, there exists $x,y \in A$ such that both properties hold. Then, I replaced $\delta$ with $\delta_n$ instead and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I get $x_n,y_n \in A$ which satisfy the given properties.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof which uses, as I mentioned in my comment, the [Lebesgue number lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma):

Let $\epsilon>0$. For each $x\in A\subseteq \Omega$, as $f$ is continuous at $x$, there is some $\delta_x$ such that
$$f(B_{\delta_x}(x))\subseteq B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(f(x))\hspace{1cm}i.e. \;\;d(x,y)<\delta_x \implies d'(f(x),f(y))<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
for given $\epsilon>0$. We take the open cover of $A$  $\left\{B_{\frac{\delta_x}{2}}(x) : x\in A\right\}$. Since $X$ is compact, it admits a Lebesgue number $\lambda>0$ and thus, given $x\in A$ there is some $z\in A$ such that $B_\lambda(x)\subseteq B_{\frac{\delta_z}{2}}(z)$ and then
$$f(B_\lambda(x))\subseteq f(B_{\frac{\delta_z}{2}}(z))\subseteq B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(f(z))$$

Also, since $x\in B_\lambda(x)\subseteq B_{\frac{\delta_z}{2}}(z)$ we have that  $f(x)\in B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(f(z))$ so, for any given $y\in B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(f(z))$: $$d(y,f(x))\leq d(y,f(z))+d(f(z),f(x))<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$ which shows that  $B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(f(z))\subseteq B_\epsilon(f(x))$ and therefore, for that fixed $\lambda$ $$f(B_\lambda(x))\subseteq B_\epsilon(f(x)) \hspace{1cm} i.e. \;\; d(x,y)<\lambda \implies d'(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$$ for arbitrary $x$. This shows that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $A$.